# Plotting multiple networks where the node width is scaled the same across each network?

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, sna, ggraph

This is my first question on Stack overflow. I'm conducting a social network analysis using the packages `igraph` and creating visualizations using the package `ggraph` with the nodes sized by degree for relatively small networks. I am trying to plot the same network at three timepoints, where the size of each node is scaled to the in-degree of a participant.

I have been able to graph each network using something similar to the following code for each timepoint, where the network being graphed represents the same nodes at a different timepoint:

```
ggraph(networkT1, layout=kk)+
  geom_edge_fan(color="black",
                 width=0.5,
                 end_cap = circle(5,'mm'),
                 arrow = arrow(ends = "last",
                               length=unit(1.5,'mm')))+
  geom_node_point(aes(color=as.factor(nodes$gender), size=degnetworkT1))+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 12))+
  scale_color_manual(name="Participant Gender",
                       labels=c("Man","Woman","Unknown"),
                       values=c("#57467B","#55917F","#000000"))+
  theme_void()+
  labs(size="In-Degree of Participants", colour="Gender", title="Network Timepoint 1")
```

I am wondering if:

1. it would be possible to make the width/scale of the nodes consistent across each of the graphs. For example, the maximum size of the nodes is consistent across each timepoint (i.e., a node with an in-degree of 6 (the max for time point 1) is the same size in the timepoint 1 graph as a node with in-degree 4 (the max for timepoint 2) in the timepoint 2 graph. I would like the node scaling to be the same across graphs 1 and 2 so that a node with in-degree 6 in the timepoint 1 graph is larger than a node with an in-degree of 4 in the timepoint 2 graph.
2. Would it be possible to combine these graphs into one image? I cannot facet-wrap by timepoint these networks since I cannot assign timepoints to the node data/adjacency matrices.

Thank you very much and please let me know if I can help clarify my question!

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow! It's often easiest to get answers if your example code can reproduce the problem.

To get to two plots with a similar problem as you describe:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(patchwork)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(highschool)

# Create two graphs representing two timepoints
set.seed(0)
g1 <- g2 <- graph

# Set some dummy node sizes seperately for each timepoint
V(g1)$size <- sample(1:3, length(V(g1)), replace = TRUE)
V(g2)$size <- sample(1:10, length(V(g2)), replace = TRUE)

p1 <- ggraph(create_layout(g1, "stress")) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = size)) +
  geom_edge_link()

p2 <- ggraph(create_layout(g2, "stress")) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = size)) +
  geom_edge_link()

p1 | p2
```

[image]

As you can see in the graphs above, the nodes have similar sizes although they depict different size-to-value translations.

The way to fix this is to set a common scale for the `size` aesthetic for both plots:

```r
common_scale <- scale_size_area(limits = c(0, 10))

p1 <- p1 + common_scale
p2 <- p2 + common_scale

p1 | p2
```

[image]

With regards to combining plots, the {patchwork} package typically does a good job and you can even combine the two legends if they're the same:

```r
(p1 | p2) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been looking for a solution all day to no avail; your response worked like a charm. I'll make sure to add in code that reproduces my issue (like your answer did) in the future.